# Whatsapp link not working for ios

Tags: android, html, ios, iphone, whatsapp

In my mobile web, there's a link that lets you share the page through Whatsapp. Basically, it's an anchor element with a `whatsapp://send` value in its `href`.

It works perfectly if I use it with an Android device, but when I click it with my iPhone (tested with iPhone 5s, iOS 8 and Safari), it opens the WhatsApp app but the share text isn't actually copied in the text field.
This is my code:

`<a class="whatsapp" href="whatsapp://send?text=This is the text that I wanna share." data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share with whatsapp!</a>`

What's the matter with it?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try replacing spaces with `%2C%20`?

Comment: @ScottFitsimones Yep, already did it, but still doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to also escape the following symbols inside the value for text: !*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]
This was an issue that I had when trying to share a url.

Comment: Yes!! That's what I did, but instead of doing it manually, I think I did it with a php function! But thanks!!